# When to choose the word suit and fit

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

This question is something to do with a sense that means "to make someone look more attractive"..

In my the first imaginary situation,I meet a friend of mine who started to wear glasses.So I would like to say that the glasses she wears look good on her and a subtle thing is that I don't want to imply your new glasses better than old ones or this color  is better, I want to imply you look better with glasses (and this is first time I see her with glasses).Should I say:

> 1.The glasses suit you.
>
> 2.The glasses fit (on) you.

If both are ok, is there any difference in terms of meaning?

---

And a situation in which a friend of mine who asks which one I should wear for the party , blue or black shirt?Can I say?

> 1.I think you should go for blue one .It suits you because your eyes are blue too.So they match.
>
> 2.I think you should go for blue one .It fits (on) you because your eyes are blue too.So they
>
> match.

If both are ok, is there any difference in terms of meaning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The blue dress fits you perfectly, but it just doesn't suit you, because your eyes are brown/shoes are green/anything....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part, I would say:

> Glasses **suit** you.

though it would be more natural to say:

> Glasses **look good on** you.

*Glasses* should be treated as a mass noun, since you are not pointing out a specific kind. So no article is used. And *suit* is better than *fit*, since *fit* has more to do with size.

In the second part, I would say:

> I think you should go for *the* blue one. It suits you because your eyes are blue too. So they match.

or simpler:

> I think you should go for *the* blue one. It suits you because **they match** your **blue** eyes.

Answer (score 1):

If something makes you look attractive, the use of "suit" is right instead of "fit"
which means to be of the right shape and size for you.

The glasses suit you.  The glasses fit you. Both the sentences are grammatically correct, with the difference mentioned above in the first paragraph.

You can also say "the glasses become you", but that's a bit formal or old-fashioned.